# How to unmask US mobile number format while making an API call in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While sending data to server I want to unmask us formatted mobile number from (222) 2222-2222 to 2222222222. Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Below my code to format as US mobile number format.

```
handleChange(e) {
    var formattedNumber = e.target.value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
}
```

Now its formatting as (xxx) xxxx-xxxx.

How I will unmask the formatted number while sending to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var str = "(222) 2222-2222 ";
console.log(str.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
```

So during the submit action you could change `formattedNumber` using the above `String.replace()` method.